# Python Fetching Name Of All CSV Files From Path And Writing Each To Different Folder

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to open all files from a folder, store them in a dataframe and append each csv file with another csv file called **Append.csv** and am trying to write all the files with their names to a different folder.

For example I have 5 csv files that are saved in a folder called **CSV FILES FOLDER**. These files are **F1.csv**, **F2.csv**, **F3.csv**, **F4.csv**and **F5.csv**. What I am trying to do is open each file using pandas and I do this in a for loop, **Append.csv** and now store it in a different folder called **NEW CSV FILES FOLDER** as :

```
F1_APPENDED.csv 
F2_APPENDED.csv
F3_APPENDED.csv
F4_APPENDED.csv
```

In other words, the _APPENDED is added with each file and then the file with the new name having _APPENDED is saved.

I have already defined the path for this folder but cant save it. The code is as below :

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os.path
import pathlib

path =r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\CSV FILES FOLDER'

allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

path1 = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\Different Folder\Bitcoin Prices Hourly Based.csv'

outpath = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\NEW CSV FILES FOLDER'



for f in allFiles:
    file = open(f, 'r')
df1 = pd.read_csv(path1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(f)
output = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="created_at")
df3 = output.created_at.value_counts().rename_axis('created_at').reset_index(name='count')
df3 = df3.sort_values(by=['created_at'])
#print(df3,'\n\n')
df3.to_csv(outpath+f, encoding='utf-8',index=False)
#print(f,'\n\n')
```

How can I do this? I tried to look up the official documentation but couldn't understand anything

Any and all help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: what is failing? You said you can't save it but failed to provide the full error output.

Comment: I get the error : **Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\\Desktop\\Different FolderC:\\Users\\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\\Desktop\\Different Folder\\adam3us_tweets.csv**

Comment: That path seems very wrong, that can be the cause of your problems. Read it - it includes the folder name twice!!

Comment: When you get f from allFiles, it includes the path, you should use 
`path, filename = os.path.split(path/to/file/foobar.txt)` to just get the filename without the path

Answer (score 0):

Here, I added a line in the for loop where you can get just the file name. You can use that instead of the full path to the file when you write the file and indicate the output .csv filename.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os.path
import pathlib

path =r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\CSV FILES FOLDER'

allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

path1 = r'C:/Users/Ahmed Ismail Khalid/Desktop/Different Folder/Bitcoin Prices Hourly Based.csv'

# You need to have a slash at the end so it knows it's a folder
outpath = r'C:/Users/Ahmed Ismail Khalid/Desktop/NEW CSV FILES FOLDER/'



for f in allFiles:
    file = open(f, 'r')
    _, fname = os.path.split(f)
    fname, ext = os.path.splittext(fname)

    df1 = pd.read_csv(path1)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(f)
    output = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="created_at")
    df3 = output.created_at.value_counts().rename_axis('created_at').reset_index(name='count')
    df3 = df3.sort_values(by=['created_at'])
    #print(df3,'\n\n')
    df3.to_csv(outpath+fname+'_appended.csv', encoding='utf-8',index=False)
    #print(f,'\n\n')
```

Comment: Instead of writing it to the output folder it writes to Desktop now even though I have created NEW CSV FILES FOLDER. Also I want to save the files with the following convention : **F1_APPENDED.csv**,**F2_APPENDED.csv** etc

Comment: You need a backslash after your output path filename, or else it won't recognize as a new folder...I updated my answer to addresss your issues.

Comment: Now it gives Syntax Error : **SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal**

Comment: you need to give more information when writing about errors, i.e. what's the traceback, where is the error. If it's the backslashes, can you switch to forward slashes as in the updated example?